# Replace a sequence of 3 to 30 characters by another one with regex

Tags: regex, eclipse

I need to replace sequences (of various length) of characters by another character. I am working in Eclipse on xml files

For exemple `--------` should be replaced by `********`.

The replacement should be done only for sequences of at least 3 characters, not 1 or 2.

It is easy to find the matching sequences in regex for example with `-{3,30}` but I don't understand how to specify the replacement sequence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
(?:\G(?!\A)|(?<!-)(?=-{3,30}(?!-)))-
```

See the [regex pattern](https://regex101.com/r/v56bgf/1). *Details*:

- `(?:\G(?!\A)|(?<!-)(?=-{3,30}(?!-)))` - either

  - `\G(?!\A)` - end of the preceding match
  - `|` - or
  - `(?<!-)(?=-{3,30}(?!-))` - a position that is not immediately preceded with a `-` char  and is immediately followed with 3 to 30 hyphens (not followed with another hyphen).
- `-` - a hyphen.

The `(?:\G(?!\A)|(?<!-)(?=-{3,30}(?!-)))-` regex goes into the "Find What" filed, `*` goes to the "Replace With" field.

Note that regular expressions are only meant to be used in *search* fields, replacement fields must only contain *replacement* patterns. Usually, the replacement pattern is a string containing literal string(s) and/or backreferences. Here, we do not need any backreference as the regex does not capture anything.

Comment: Thank you but how does it match with the "search and replace" window ? This is what I don't understand: I need a regex for the search and a regex for the replace right ?

Comment: @GuillaumePetitjean I updated the question with the clarification.

Comment: So the regex is working (when i click on Find it finds only the right hyphens) but the replace does nothing.

Comment: @GuillaumePetitjean When you need to replace a `-` with `*`, just use `*` in the replacement field. That is all there is to it.

Comment: Yes this is clear. As I wrote, the regex works just fine, but the replace does nothing. I'm probably missing something.

Comment: Might be related to this: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=109481

Answer (score 2):

I made this regex solution ready when question was posted but didn't submit an answer because I kept testing in eclipse and even though regex was working for `find` feature, a `*` in replacement wasn't changing text in Eclipse editor.

Here is a shorter and a bit more efficient regex:

```bash
(?!^)\G-|(?=-{3})-
```

Replace with a `*`

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sj6e1q/1)

**Breakdown:**

- `(?!^)\G`: Match from end of the previous match
- `-`: Match a `-`
- `|`: OR
- `(?=-{3})`: Make sure we have 3 hyphens ahead
- `-`: Match a `-`

Here is a screenshot from my Eclipse that shows selected match for this regex:

[image]